# Stocktrack webscrapping?

Tags: equities, vba

Is it possible to scrape data from stocktrack.com into Microsoft Excel? I have been writing VBA code but the password protection might be a problem because none of my code works. I'm starting back at ground zero.

Does anyone have experience scraping data from Stocktrack.com?

Comment: Scraping is not on-topic here and probably against the Stocktrack.com/Stocktrak.com TOS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because web scraping is off-topic.

Comment: @BobJansen your comment got mangled I think by the close reason

Comment: @chollida More likely I messed up, thanks!

Comment: Actually I would argue that webscrapping stock data from sources other than yahoo, google, and bloomberg has significant ties to quant finance